# How can I enter predefined text into the active cell as plain text?

Tags: excel, vba, keyboard-shortcuts

I wish to press <kbd>F1</kbd> (Windows OS) to print, i.e., "XZ" in the active Excel cell (as plain/unformatted text), but in such a way that I can then enter "123" immediately thereafter, hence resulting in a cell value of XZ123.

This `.xls` is shared by other users, four of whom are in the document adding data at any given time. We save this to a SharePoint folder, but nobody on the team ever accesses the document via the web version of Excel. We instead just double-click the document, at which point Excel boots up from our local hard drive, but when the document loads, we can see other users' active cell(s) based on highlights around the cells with their initials.

My hope is that this two-letter automation can be triggered from my computer, and not embedded in the document file itself.

Comment: Unfortunately the only way for vba to enter edit mode is to use SendKeys

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only way for vba to enter edit mode is to use [`SendKeys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.sendkeys)

You'll need to use [`OnKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.onkey) to map the function to `F1`

```vb
Const StringToEnter As String = "XZ"

Sub EnterValue()
    Application.SendKeys "{F2}" & StringToEnter
End Sub

' Run this once to map F1 key.  Maybe call from the `Workbook_Open` event
Sub SetupMappingToF1()
    Application.OnKey "{F1}", "EnterValue"
End Sub
```